# Reshape data frame in R: rows to columns

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, dataframe, reshape

there are 3 columns in the original data frame: id, type and rank. Now I want to create a new data frame having each possible value of type as a single column (see the small example below, the original data contains >100.000 rows and 30 types)

```
data1
id  type  rank
x   a     1
y   a     2
z   a     3
x   b     1
z   b     2
y   c     1     

data2
id  a  b  c
x   1  1  NA
y   2  NA  1
z   3  2  NA
```

That's what I have done so far:

```
for (i in (1:nrow(data1))) {
  dtype <- data[i,2]
  if (any(data2$id == data1[i,1], na.rm = TRUE)) {
    row <- grep(data1[i,1],data2$id)
    data2[row,c(dtype)] <- data1[i,3]
  } else {
    data2[nrow(data2)+1,1] <- as.character(data1[i,1])
    data2[nrow(data2),c(dtype)] <- data1[i,3]
 }
}
```

This works (I hope this example explains what I am doing), but it is quite slow. Do you have any hints how I can optimize this algorithm?

Comment: Is the "id" unique for all 100k rows or are there duplicated values in that column?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example from the `tidyr` package.

```
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
data2<-
   data1 %>% spread(type, rank)

  id a  b  c
1  x 1  1 NA
2  y 2 NA  1
3  z 3  2 NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the function by the word mentioned in your question, you can just use `reshape` from base R:

```
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "type")
  id rank.a rank.b rank.c
1  x      1      1     NA
2  y      2     NA      1
3  z      3      2     NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
ans = dcast.data.table(setDT(data1), id ~ type)
ans
#    id a  b  c
# 1:  x 1  1 NA
# 2:  y 2 NA  1
# 3:  z 3  2 NA
```